# Instagram search by area

Tags: instagram

I'm starting with Instagram API and I notice that there is no way to search media for a certain area. API only lets me to search through lat/long. Is there anyway to get media from an area? For example Flickr's API lets to ask for regions/counties...

In other case, any idea to do this in a simple way?

Thanks in advance,

Regards

Answer (score 3):

You have two ways of doing this with the Instagram api:

Use the get media/search endpoint to find media for an area defined by lat/lng and a radius. You can specify a radius up to 5000 meters to capture media for a large area.

```
api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?lat=48.858844&lng=2.294351&distance=5000
```

Use the /locations/location-id/media/recent endpoint to find media assigned to locations. Some cities, towns, regions, etc are set up as locations. These aren't very reliable and there are often duplicates. You would need to use the /locations/search endpoint to find the location id's first.

```
api.instagram.com/v1/locations/514276/media/recent
```

Comment: Thanks you very much @Bill Rollins. That's what I'm thinking on. My problem is that I would like to get media from an administrative area for example, so searching with a radius is not so accurate... The other option to search locations ids also has to provide lat/long so for a specific point it's good but not for adminstrative area... Anyway thanks a lot.

Comment: @Hugo, what do you mean by an administrative area?

Comment: I mean a region (towns and cities geopolitically delimited). For instance, [Barcelona, Spain](http://goo.gl/vzS0V) is a city and is also inside a region called "Catalunya" (there are some dotted lines delimiting) so I would like to know if there is any option to know how can I get media from that area instead of trying to get from a point+radius that is not accurated. Flickr for example has internally delimited that "Catalunya" is a shape and knows if a location is inside or not.